# DL query for individuals not connected to others by a property

Tags: owl, protege, description-logic

I have an OWL ontology with three interconnected individuals: **a**, **b**, and **c**, and also has two isolated individuals **x**, and **y**.

**interconnected individuals**:

1. have at least one outbound object property assertion. e.g.: **a hasRelationWith b**; or
2. have at least on inbound object property assertion e.g.: **such c, as b hasRelationWith c**.

**isolated individuals**:

1. have zero outbound object property assertion e.g.: **x hasRelationWith [no individual]**; and
2. have zero inbound object property assertion e.g.: **such x, as [no individual] hasRelationWith x**.

Is it possible to classify (by logical inference, not by enumeration) all the isolated individuals using a DL Query (in Protégé 4.3, if it makes a difference), and if it is possible, how do I do it?

My intuitive guess is something like: (hasRelationWith min 0 Thing) **exclude** (hasRelationWith min 1 Thing), but DL-Query seems not supporting Set Subtraction syntax...

---

UPDATE: The following SPARQL can make it, although it cannot be used within class definition.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX my: <http://localhost:8080/ontology/untitled-ontology-26#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?src_obj
WHERE {
  ?src_obj a owl:NamedIndividual .
  minus {?src_obj my:hasRelationWith ?target_obj}
  minus {?target_obj my:hasRelationWith ?src_obj}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query about what's logically provable.  That means that if you can *infer* that some individual isn't related to any others by some property, you can ask about it.  For instance, if you have disjoint classes `Cat` and `Dog`, so that nothing can be an instance of both, and you have a `Person` `jim` who also has the additional type `hasPet only Cat and Dog`, then a reasoner can infer that `jim hasPet exactly 0`.

In the DL query language, you can also use *inverse* properties.  The previous example showed that `jim` has no pets (i.e., is an instance of `hasPet exactly 0`).  You could ask for animals that aren't the pets of anyone by asking for instances of `inverse hasPet exactly 0`.  For instance, if you add disjoint subclasses of `Person`, `ThisKind` and `ThatKind`, and say that `missy` the `Cat` `inverse hasPet only ThisKind and ThatKind`, then a reasoner can infer that no one is related *to* `missy` by the `hasPet` property. An ontology for these two examples is given at the end of this answer.

For your particular query, you just combine two class expressions of the forms I've just described:

> hasRelationWith exactly 0 and inverse hasRelationWith exactly 0

or, with some parenthesis:

> (hasRelationWith exactly 0) and ((inverse hasRelationWith) exactly 0)

It is very important to note, however, that this only returns individuals for which it can be *proven* that there are no such relations.  It's not enough for the data to simply not contain such relations yet.  OWL makes the [open world assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_world_assumption), meaning something that isn't explicitly stated or provable isn't assumed to be true or false.

#### Example ontology

```
@prefix :      <http://www.example.org/cardinality-example#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

:fido   a       owl:NamedIndividual , :Dog .

:Dog    a       owl:Class .

:fluffy  a      owl:NamedIndividual , :Cat ;
        a       [ a                   owl:Class ;
                  owl:intersectionOf  ( :ThatKind [ a                  owl:Restriction ;
                                                    owl:allValuesFrom  :ThisKind ;
                                                    owl:onProperty     [ owl:inverseOf  :hasPet ]
                                                  ] )
                ] .

:ThatKind  a              owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf   :Person ;
        owl:disjointWith  :ThisKind .

:rover  a       owl:NamedIndividual , :Dog .

:hasPet  a      owl:ObjectProperty .

<http://www.example.org/cardinality-example>
        a       owl:Ontology .

:Person  a      owl:Class .

:jim    a       owl:NamedIndividual , :Person ;
        a       [ a                owl:Restriction ;
                  owl:cardinality  "0"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
                  owl:onProperty   :hasPet
                ] .

:missy  a       owl:NamedIndividual , :Cat .

:Cat    a                 owl:Class ;
        owl:disjointWith  :Dog .

:ThisKind  a             owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  :Person .
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed and so neatly explained answer! I have thought that it could be related to the Open World assumption. But I do need your answer to confirm. 

After your explanation I understand that an instance without explict class restrictions/data properties can not be queried that way.

Comment: @PIMGeek Yes, to get an answer that "this thing isn't *known* to be connected to anything (so far as the system knows)", you'd need some kind of default reasoning or negation as failure.  Your best bet in that case is probably to use a [tag:SPARQL] query.

Comment: Thanks, I finally made it with SPARQL to filter out the Isolated Individuals. I view your comment as extra bonus.